# Load test with JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I need to conduct a load test with 500, 1000, 1500, and 2000 users on JMeter. How can I configure the Thread Group to achieve this?

Any help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

[image]

Then you need [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) plugin, it can be installed as a part of **Custom Thread Groups** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Otherwise describe your desired workload model in details

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your quick response. Otherwise, I used the Ultimate Thread Group plugin with the suggested configuration. However, I have the following remarks regarding the "View Results in Table" where I see the dates "01:00:00.000". I'm wondering if there's a configuration to fix this. The second remark is whether it's normal to have more than 2000 samplers (as shown in table report with 16389 samplers).